# webview in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, scroll

I am  showing a particular website in `UIWebView` were it shows the entire website.
The problem is that I need to scroll lengthwise and breathwise to see the content, what I want is the entire website to fit the screen with the letters minimized and not to scroll lengthwise or breadthwise.

below is the code I use:

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad 
 {

  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.title=@"MainSite";

  [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
  self.urlAddress4 = @"http://www.livingwaterscf.org/";

  self.url4 = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress4];

  self.requestObj4 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url4];

  NSURLConnection *connection=[[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:self.requestObj4 delegate:self]autorelease];

  [webViewGive loadRequest:requestObj4];

  //[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
 }
 -(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
 {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
 }

 - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView 
{
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set property scalesPageToFit to YES on your web view and your done!

Like:

`webViewGive.scalesPageToFit=YES;`

Answer (score 4):

You probably want this :

```
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```